# Dynamically Generate the Expression for @Html.EditorFor in ASP .NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a completely configurable Entity Framework Model. By configurable I mean the user can choose which fields are visible or not, required or not and read-only or not. I applied the configuration by overriding the DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider class, now the problem is using the Model with Html.EditorFor Helper.

I wan't to loop through each property and add Html.EditorFor Like the following

```
@foreach(var field in fieldConfig)
{
    Html.EditorFor(...Dynamicaly Created Expression...)
}
```

EDIT:
fieldConfig is list from ConfigTable and it contains fields like FieldName, IsRequred, IsReadOnly, OrderNo, Type

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You want your 'dynamic expression' to be a string, you may use

```
Html.Editor("MyProperty")
```

or even

```
Html.Editor("MyProperty.AnotherProperty.Name")
```

instead.

It takes a string expression and works just the same way as EditorFor, but not typesafe.

Or You wan't to be typesafe and learn how to create expression trees: http://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/archive/2009/11/29/understanding-csharp-3-0-features-6-lambda-expression.aspx

Comment: Thanks Hannes, But I actually needed to be type-safe.

Comment: You're welcome, I’ve added a very helpful link about composing lambda expressions, which helped me in a similar scenario. It’s hard to work through but once you understand the topic it's pretty useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
@foreach(var field in fieldConfig)
{
Html.EditorFor(model=> field)
}
```

Last time I've used it it worked

Comment: The "field" actualy is in another table (config table)

Comment: The view works with view models, NOT tables. Put in the view model everything the view needs, regardless from where the data comes from

Comment: I could but Like I said the Model Configurable. So I cant really create view model dynamically.

Comment: What?! You're messing things big time here. The view model should contains ONLY data required by the view. I don't know what "Model Configurable" means but it doesn't sound very good. Have the controller or a service populate the view model and use it. This is how you keep responsibilities where they belong (separation of concerns)

Comment: Hire is the thing... The app is an online Document Processing System..., And Every time a client is registered they choose which fields of Invoice Model they need, which ones are required... So I really Can't Create a View Model and View each time a client is registed. The The only way I can handle this is if I can create dynamicaly generated view. Also the DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider takes care of the DataAnotation, So...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like that, by using reflection you can get your class' properties. I didn't try so your can check on your side:

```
var properties = Model.GetType().GetProperties();


foreach (var field in properties)
{
    Html.EditorFor(model => field.GetValue(Model, null));
}
```